# Mapping user site to their own url in a web.py application

Tags: python, web.py, url-mapping

I'm coding a web app with web.py allowing users to add some html pages.

Currently, the pages are mapping like that:

```
webapp.com/user1/page1
webapp.com/user1/page2
webapp.com/user2/page1
webapp.com/user3/page1
```

I know web.py can manage subdomains to have:

```
user1.webapp.com/page1
user2.webapp.com/page2
...
```

If the user would like his pages to appear under a custom domain URL that he control, such as www.user-own-url.com, I would like to give him the option.

Is it possible to do it with web.py? Or is there another python solutions to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you'll have to subclass application class and code your own url mapping so it will depend on web.ctx.host value instead of just [matching against web.ctx.path](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/application.py#L228)

Or you may add [loadhook](http://webpy.org/cookbook/application_processors) for every request, where you check web.ctx.host and load needed user into [web.ctx](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx) to use later in the controller method.

Comment: as complement of information for the process, what settings the user must change for his own domain?  CNAME? A-record?

Comment: CNAME is domain redirect, A record points to ip. I think CNAME is better because won't depend on ip change. So basically they should point CNAME to userX.webapp.com, and let your app know of the change.

Comment: Thank you very much!  All works but I still have to manually add the user-own-domain.com to my host provider. No way to do it programaticly...

Comment: Some hostings have API to do things automatically, otherwise I think you have to purchase dedicated server with your own web server catching requests for all domains.

Comment: Another way I think probably would be purchasing dedicated ip address from the hosting, so it will not have to proxy the request based on domain name. I don't have enough knowledge in domains, maybe you should open a question on serverfault.